# Scraping Data using task parallel Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I am parsing html pages and scarping data from the websites using task parallel library, i want to store the data in sqlite using entity framework. I have created servers and a crawlDb class. i have also created two methods which are query data and insert data. My question is how should i store the data in sqlite and show table data

Answer (score 0):

IMO It depends on how you are planning to use the scraped data. Now you have a collection of scraped data. You have to form your data into a proper structure it could be relational or nonrelational. Since you have decided to go with sqllite you can see whether you can form your data into a relational model. First of all, think about how you are going to use this data. That's the key question

Comment: this is my code ;-if (!Db.Crawling.Any())
    {
        foreach(var item in CrawlingData)
        {
            Db.Crawling.Add(item);

        }


        Db.SaveChanges();